# Why do I have GenCodeChecksum uncommitted changes after a fresh civibuild create?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, civibuild

I just created a new site with buildkit:

```
$ civibuild create foo --url http://foo --type drupal-demo
```

Then I went into CiviCRM and looked at the git repo

```
$ cd ~/buildkit/build/foo/sites/all/modules/civicrm
$ git status
```

and I see:

```
    modified:   CRM/Case/DAO/Case.php
    modified:   CRM/Core/DAO/AllCoreTables.data.php
    modified:   CRM/Financial/DAO/PaymentProcessor.php
```

Why? I would expect the repo to be clean after a fresh install. The diffs for these files show a different value for `GenCodeChecksum` within the docblock header for the file, and that's the entirety of the uncommitted changes. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr**: It's safe but mildly annoying. Please feel free to send a pull-request to update these files.

**Longer**: DAO files are auto-generated when `civibuild` calls the script `xml/GenCode.php` with the data in `xml/schema`. However, running `GenCode` is traditionally pretty slow -- even on a fast workstation, it can add 30 seconds to the build-time.

Starting somewhere in 4.7.x, we did an optimization: if the checksum looks right, then `GenCode` keeps the DAO. (Hooray, faster!) If the checksum looks wrong, then it regenerates the DAO.

In a typical scenario, you might edit a file in `xml/schema`, then run `GenCode`, then observe several changes to your local DAO. The `GenCodeChecksum` would be one of several changes. You'd commit those changes and send them in with the PR.

Right now, I see something like what you describe -- the *only* difference between the upstream DAO and the local DAO is the checksum. This can happen occasionally (eg if there were contemporaneous PRs manipulating schema and the precise order-of-operations was unfavorable). The consequences are:

- `GenCode` spends an extra second regenerating 1-3 files.
- Your `git diff` shows something unexpected on 1-3 files.

That's mildly annoying - but you still wind up with the right code, so it's safe.

You can fix it by submitting a PR to update the DAO's with the latest `GenCodeChecksum`.